# Node js / Express js res.write fails but res.send works. What would cause this?

Tags: node.js, express

I am experiencing a issue that has me baffled. When using Node with Express, if I use res.write and res.end, no data gets sent and there is no error generated, however if I use res.send, the data gets sent.

Nodejs version 8.9.4, 
Expressjs version 4.16.2

This does not work:

```
res.write(data);
res.end;
```

This does work:

```
res.send(data);
```

Now my function looks like this:

```
app.post('/getData'), function (req,res)
{
  let p;
  let key = mysql.escape(req.body.key);

  // response.writeHead(200, {'content-type', 'application/json'});
  // changed to the below so I could use res.send
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');

  let query = "SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE key = " + key;
  p = P_GetQueryData(query, ParseDataFunction);
  p.then(data => {
    res.send(data);
    // previously had the below
    // res.write(data);
    // res.end;
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });
});
```

The only thing I can think us, is I recently switched to using promises to take care of a flaw where I was using global variables and maybe res.write / res.end doesn't work inside of a .then ?

Comment: `res.end;` should be `res.end();` it's a function and you need to call it otherwise it won't do anything. But why would you use longer version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.end` will return the function definition and not terminating the request/response cycle as expected, you should use parenthesis:

```
res.write(data);
res.end();
```

Comment: Yes, that is the correct answer... somehow I just didn't see this... the other code I replaced when changing to promises had the () in it, and somehow it got lost and I didn't notice it, and since it didn't generate an error I didn't realize what the problem was.

Comment: doesn't works for me,  res.write(result); 
   ` res.write(pageTargeted);
    res.write(data)
    res.end();` doesn't works but `    data.push({result}, {pageTargeted})
    res.status(200).send(data)` works